# CMS template data: Database vs file system?

Tags: php, database, content-management-system, static-files

For a PHP CMS (wolfCMS in this case, but I imagine the question is relevant for any PHP CMS), and from a performance and backup point of view, where is better to store template data (layout files)?

In a database entry, or in a .php file in the file system. Or even somewhere else all together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, databases will win everytime you need to find data in a flexible way. Filesystems will work anytime you need to find something in a *fixed* way (i.e., a pathname).

Would you be using the analogue of a file name as the index in your database? Or do you need to filter it in various ways based on a number of criteria in order to pick the appropriate template?

Comment: Normal situation, it would just be one template. For the more advanced user though (like me), they will want to change the template for a mobile version perhaps. The template may also need to pull other "snippets" of code depending on the content being displayed. The CMS already stores "snippets" as a database entries.